# while loop string index out of range , python, newbie

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

i'm a newbie and i started to learn python,
i need to achieve the below goal , make the while loop stop if it's encounter an error like index out of range.

something wrong :IndexError: string index out of range.

here is the below code: could u help me guys ?

```
def mystery(st):
## Modify anything you want in this function:
i = 0
count = 0
while st[i] != '.' or len(st) >= 1:


    if st[i] in 'aeiou':
        count = count + 1
    i = i + 1
  


return count


### TESTS ###

print("********************")
print("Starting the test:")

print("********************")
print("Checking 'hello. world.'")
ans = mystery('hello. world.')
 if ans == 2:
   print("CORRECT: 'hello. world.' has 2 vowels before the first period")
 else:
    print("WRONG: 'hello. world.' has 2 vowels before the first period but the code returned",         ans)

print("********************")
print("Checking 'hello world. nice to meet you.'")
ans = mystery('hello world. nice to meet you.')
 if ans == 3:
    print("CORRECT: 'hello world. nice to meet you.' has 3 vowels before the first period")
 else:
   print("WRONG: 'hello world. nice to meet you.' has 3 vowels before the first period but the        code returned", ans)

 print("********************")
 print("Checking ' '")
ans = mystery(' ')
 if ans == 0:
   print("CORRECT: The string ' ' has no vowels")
else:
   print("WRONG: The string ' ' has no vowels but the code returned", ans)

print("********************")
print("Checking 'dddda'")
ans = mystery('dddda')
  if ans == 1:
print("CORRECT: 'dddda' has 1 vowel")
 else:
   print("WRONG: 'dddda' has 1 vowel but the code returned", ans)

print("********************")    
print("Tests concluded, add more tests of your own below!")
print("********************")
```

Comment: You have `st[i]` in your while condition, which runs right after `i = i + 1` in the loop. Meaning you're not doing anything to prevent `i` from being out of range. You have to design your loop so that it doesn't ever try to access any values past the end of the list.

Comment: `while st[i] != '.' or len(st) >= 1:` could run "forever" (until you get an error) if '.' is not in `st` and `st` is not empty.

Comment: `while i < len(st) and st[i] != '.':`

Comment: hi, tried the below : 'while st[i] != '.' and k != " " and i <= len(st):'                               , and still index out of range

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the loop without termination of the procedure (i.e. to reach the ‘return’) then just wrap this ‘while’ into try: ... except block

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: i can't use the except block ... it's really the solution...:>

Answer (score 0):

i succeeded answering my own question!!! yes!!!
here is the code:

```
    i = 0
count = 0
k = st
z = len(st)
while st[i] != '.' and k != " ":
    
    if st[i] in 'aeiou':
        count = count + 1
    i = i + 1
    if i >= z:
        break

return count

### TESTS ###

print("********************")
print("Starting the test:")

print("********************")
print("Checking 'hello. world.'")
ans = mystery('hello. world.')
   if ans == 2:
      print("CORRECT: 'hello. world.' has 2 vowels before the first period")
   else:
      print("WRONG: 'hello. world.' has 2 vowels before the first period but the  code returned", ans)

print("********************")
print("Checking 'hello world. nice to meet you.'")
ans = mystery('hello world. nice to meet you.')
if ans == 3:
    print("CORRECT: 'hello world. nice to meet you.' has 3 vowels before the first  period")
else:
    print("WRONG: 'hello world. nice to meet you.' has 3 vowels before the first   period but the code returned", ans)

   print("********************")
   print("Checking ' '")
   ans = mystery(' ')
   if ans == 0:
       print("CORRECT: The string ' ' has no vowels")
   else:
       print("WRONG: The string ' ' has no vowels but the code returned", ans)

   print("********************")
   print("Checking 'dddda'")
   ans = mystery('dddda')
   if ans == 1:
       print("CORRECT: 'dddda' has 1 vowel")
   else:
      print("WRONG: 'dddda' has 1 vowel but the code returned", ans)

   print("********************")    
   print("Tests concluded, add more tests of your own below!")
   print("********************")
```

'''
'''